# Fineract CN Basic Setup

Tags: mifos, apache-fineract

I have followed the setup detailed on this link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FINERACT/Bare+minimum+to+run+Fineract-CN+locally but it appears there are some properties that are missing such as:

```
fin.keycloak.realm.publicKey=
conf.enableAccountLevelAccessVerification=
keycloak.auth-server-url=
keycloak.realm=
keycloak.resource=
keycloak.public-client=
keycloak.principal-attribute=
keycloak.ssl-required=
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=
```

I am failing to complete the setup at the stage of running the Postman Scripts

postman_scripts/Fineract-Cn-Initial-Requests.postman_collection.json
postman_scripts/Fineract-Cn-Initial-Setup-Environment.postman_environment.json

Anyone who has managed to get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was getting the same error. Introduce the in the environment.

.env_keycloak
[.env_keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UqM5.png)

Then on your docker-compose.yml as per https://github.com/apache/fineract-cn-docker-compose,

I added this: Note the env_file addition.
[docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow4Kt.png)
Be sure to add in other services you need.

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

According to Fineract CN Bare minimum locally link, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FINERACT/Bare+minimum+to+run+Fineract-CN+locally, I Add these properties were located in fineract-cn-docker-compose/keycloak-config folder to application.yml at provisioner project.

```
authentication:
  service:
    anubis: true
    keycloak: false
conf:
  enableAccountLevelAccessVerification: false
fin:
  keycloak:
    realm:
      publicKey: keycloak-rsa-public-key
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: https://localhost:8180/auth
  bearer-only: true
  confidential-port: 443
  enabled: false
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
  public-client: true
  realm: keycloak-realm
  resource: kecloak-client
  ssl-required: external
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have run this fine on local and on server with docker compose, found no issues, these are only required if you are using keycloak etc

Comment: Using docker its straightforward, but what I want is to then do some customisations, so I used https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FINERACT/Bare+minimum+to+run+Fineract-CN+locally  steps, but when you try to run provisioner, you start getting errors such this property is missing "fin.keycloak.realm.publicKey"

Comment: it's strange docker work only mostly like in community app, you can do customisation by adding volume

Answer (score 0):

You must add this to the application.yml file:

```
system:   
     publicKey:
          modulus: 
          exponent: 65537
          timestamp: 2021-12-06T10_53_11    privateKey:
          modulus: 
          exponent: 
     initialclientid: sillyRabbit
     identity:    passwordExpiresInDays: 93    timeToChangePasswordAfterExpirationInDays: 4 conf:    enableAccountLevelAccessVerification: false
    
    keycloak:  
      enabled: false
    
    authentication: 
       service:
          keycloak: false
          anubis: true
     fin:    keycloak:
          realm:
             publicKey: keycloak-rsa-public-key
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it